# how do I convert a string array to a numeric in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array `{'W','L','D','D','W'}`. I want to convert this into a {-1,0,1} array where 'W' is mapped to 1, 'D' to 0, and 'L' to -1.

Is there a quick way to do this without writing a loop?

Answer (score 6):

You could use `categorical` arrays to do this in a single expression

```
double(categorical({'W','L','D','D','W'}, {'L', 'D', 'W'})) - 2
```

Or for MATLAB prior to R2013b, you can do two expressions:

```
[~, loc] = ismember({'W','L','D','D','W'}, {'L', 'D', 'W'});
result = loc - 2;
```

Comment: Clever! It should be noted that `categorical` arrays were introduced in R2013b.

Comment: Sorry, introduced to base MATLAB in R2013b, I believe they have been part of the stats toolbox for a while.

Comment: Yep, added the alternative for MATLAB-only prior to R2013b.

Answer (score 4):

use `strcmp` :

```
A = {'W','L','D','D','W'};
B = strcmp (A,'W');
C = strcmp (A,'L') * -1;
B+C

ans =

 1    -1     0     0     1
```

Comment: You could also index directly with the result of `strcmp`: `B(strcmp(A, 'W')) =  1;`

Answer (score 0):

@GameOfThrows's answer is good but it would not generalize well should your character-number mapping become more complex. Here is my solution:

Create a function that maps the characters the way you want

```
function n = mapChar(c)
    if strcmp(c, 'W')
        n = 1;
    elseif strcmp(c, 'D')
        n = 0;
    elseif strcmp(c, 'L')
        n = -1;
    end
end
```

and then use [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) to apply it over the cell array:

```
>> cellfun(@mapChar, {'W','L','D','D','W'})

ans =

     1    -1     0     0     1
```

If you find that you need to use a different mapping, you just redefine your mapping.

Also, it all can be inlined (using part of the @GameOfThrows's approach):

```
>> cellfun(@(c)(strcmp(c, 'W') - strcmp(c, 'L')), {'W','L','D','D','W'})

ans =

     1    -1     0     0     1
```

Comment: None of that is necessary, `strcmp` works over cell arrays already and you can use the logical return to index your result directly. e.g. `B(strcmp(A, 'W')) = 1;`

Comment: @excaza I know, but, as I have written at the beginning of my answer, the motivation for using a separate function is that the mapping might become more complex than just ``strcmp``s. In that case it would be much easier to rewrite the one function rather than inventing a new way of how to do it with the whole arrays (which may become non-trivial). The inline version is just a bonus and, of course, is better performed with the whole arrays.

Comment: [This gist](https://gist.github.com/sco1/4441423ef6c10f7f5febfcf2d01fe667) is functionally equivalent and does not require logic control nor `cellfun`.

Comment: A `switch` statement would be more natural than `if`/`else` indoor first example.